# How to write custom comparator for std::minmax function for datatype vector<glm::vec3> (opengl datatype)

Tags: c++, comparator, glm-math, minmax

I get the following compiler error:

```
C2664:Reason: cannot convert from 'const _Ty' to 'const glm::vec3'
```

My custom comparator:

```
bool comp(glm::vec3   const & first, glm::vec3  const & sec) { return first.y > sec.y; }
```

and the code where I call this

```
 // function getVertices() returns std::vector<glm::vec3>
const std::vector<glm::vec3> verts = mesh.getVertices();
auto minmax = std::minmax(std::begin(verts), std::end(verts),comp);
```

How to fix the issue?  please help.

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question. Preferably together with a [mcve] as well.

Comment: This looks like it should work.  Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: On a side note, I doubt that you want to copy the vertices of your mesh very often.

Comment: Surprisingly I can [reproduce in an MCVE](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b87deb197943287).

Comment: this code is part of openframeworks example. complete code .             <pre> <code> #include "ofMain.h"
#include "ofApp.h"

//===========
bool comp(glm::vec3   const & first, glm::vec3  const & sec) { return first.y > sec.y; }

int main( ){

 ofMesh mesh;
 mesh.load("lofi-bunny.ply");
 const std::vector<glm::vec3> verts = mesh.getVertices();
 auto minmax = std::minmax(std::begin(verts), std::end(verts), comp);
 

}

Comment: sorry i could not format correctly, this is my first post. ;( . code is built in VS 2017

Answer (score 3):

The [`std::minmax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) function returns the min and max of two (or more) ***values***.

To get the min and max elements using a range of iterators (for example the beginning and end of a container) you should use [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).

Comment: Actually, there is an `initializer_list` version that takes more than 2 values.

Comment: But (a) this isn't an initialiser list and, even if it were, (b) then you'd be copying your data. Still not was wanted.

Comment: I changed it to  std::minmax_element. keeping other things same. it worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As 'Some programmer dude' suggested, I changed it to std::minmax_element. it worked. :)